# data isnt inserting into table java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I would like to figure out what the problem of this code is. When I fill the form and press save button the page just blink like refreshes without an error and data insertion.

I have a working table which extends the class on this table. I used a many-to-one relationship so I don't know where exactly the error is.

jsp file input

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@page import="eshop.model.Category"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<jsp:include page="header.jsp" /> 
<body>


${msg}
<div>
    <div style="float:left;width:200px">
        <jsp:include page="menu.jsp" />
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">


    <form action="ProductController"  method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add"/>

        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Product ID</td>
            <td> 
                <input type="text" name="pid"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="pname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Category Id</td>
                <td>
                    <%
                 List<Category> aList = (List) request.getAttribute("clist");
                 %>
                 <select name="cat">
                 <%
                 for(Category c : aList){
                      %>
                      <option  value="<%out.println(c.getCatId());%>">
                      <%out.println(c.getCatName() ); %>
                      </option>
                      <%    }   %>                    
                    </select>                       
                </td>           
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Supplier ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="sid" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unit Price</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="up" /></td></tr>
            <tr>           
            <td>Quantity</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="qua"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Units in Stock</td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="uis"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Units on Order</td>
                <td> 
                <input type="text" name="uoo"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Reorder</td>
                <td> 
                <input type="text" name="rol"/></td></tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="reset" value="Clear" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit"  value="save" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
     </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

servlet code complete

```
   @WebServlet("/ProductController")
   public class ProductController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ProductController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException ,IOException {
         String action = request.getParameter("action");
             ProductServices cs = new ProductServices();
              if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("add")){
                CategoryServices c=new CategoryServices();
                List<Category> aList = c.getAllCategories();
                 request.setAttribute("clist", aList);      
                 request.getRequestDispatcher("products.jsp").forward(request, response);           
                 }else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("save")){
                 Products p = new Products();
                 Category ct=new Category();                        
                 p.setPid(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pid")));                
                 p.setProductName(request.getParameter("pname"));
                 int cat=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cat"));
                 ct.setCatid(cat);               
                 p.setCatid(ct);
                 p.setSupplierId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sid")));             
                 p.setUnitPrice(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("up")));
                 p.setQuntitypunit(request.getParameter("qua"));
                 p.setUnitsInStock(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("uis")));
                 p.setUnitsOnOrder(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("uoo")));
                 p.setReorderLevel(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rol")));

                cs.addProduct(p);
                request.setAttribute("msg", "Record Saved Successfully");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("products.jsp").forward(request, response);
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request,response);
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request,response);
    }
```

this is class

```
   @Entity
   @Table (name="products")

public class Products implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name="product_id")
    private int Pid;

    @Column(name="product_name")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name="supplierid")
    private int supplierId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="categoryid")
    private  Category catid;

    @Column(name="quantity_per_unit")
    private String quntitypunit;

    @Column(name="unit_price")
    private float unitPrice;

    @Column(name="unitinstock")
    private int unitsInStock;

    @Column(name="unitonorder")
    private int unitsOnOrder;

    @Column(name="reorderlevel")
    private int reorderLevel;



    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }
    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }
    public int getSupplierId() {
        return supplierId;
    }
    public void setSupplierId(int supplierId) {
        this.supplierId = supplierId;
    }
    public Category getCatid() {
        return catid;
    }
    public void setCatid(Category catid) {
        this.catid = catid;
    }
    public String getQuntitypunit() {
        return quntitypunit;
    }
    public void setQuntitypunit(String quntitypunit) {
        this.quntitypunit = quntitypunit;
    }
    public float getUnitPrice() {
        return unitPrice;
    }
    public void setUnitPrice(float unitPrice) {
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }
    public int getUnitsInStock() {
        return unitsInStock;
    }
    public void setUnitsInStock(int unitsInStock) {
        this.unitsInStock = unitsInStock;
    }
    public int getUnitsOnOrder() {
        return unitsOnOrder;
    }
    public void setUnitsOnOrder(int unitsOnOrder) {
        this.unitsOnOrder = unitsOnOrder;
    }
    public int getReorderLevel() {
        return reorderLevel;
    }
    public void setReorderLevel(int reorderLevel) {
        this.reorderLevel = reorderLevel;
    }

    public int getPid() {
        return Pid;
    }
    public void setPid(int pid) {
        Pid = pid;
    }   

}
```

this is service code i extends it to base which is working for other table

```
public class ProductServices extends Base {
    public void addProduct(Products pro){
         save(pro);
    }
```

Comment: What error you are getting

Comment: no error just like refresh

Answer (score -1):

You should set the response object with your response, not the request object.

See your last few lines of ProcessRequest() in ProductController class

Unless this is forwarding to another request, as it may be (but I don't see that code here?)

Comment: this line adds to complete servlet code :protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  processRequest(request,response);
 }
          

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  processRequest(request,response);
 }

Comment: clist is not set due to the condition (add instead of save operation).  Also you aren't displaying your message you are setting on the request in the jsp.

Comment: i have updated the code..clist is working fine i get data in dropdown from another table the problem is when i select dropdown and fetch all fields and press save the data goes away from fields without showing any error!

Comment: I don't see it updated, it's still not being set like it is in the add block.  Look below `}else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("save")){` and search for clist.  The dropdown relies on this to populate.

Comment: in clist i am getting data from database and getting it to jsp page  in dropdown,but in "save" i am inserting into data base on insertion it shd display masg recored saved.

Comment: So where is your msg in the jsp being displayed?  I don't see anything there referencing it.